# MySQL Uses Different Memory on Different Computer

Tags: mysql, database, memory, cpu-usage

So I recently have a project using MySQL 8.0.12, configured for Development Computer upon installation.

I developed the system on my PC, which has an i5 CPU with 8 GB RAM.
On my PC, the mysqld.exe process consumes around 10% of CPU usage and 20 MB of Memory when a continuous query is run

I then deployed this system to the client PC, which has an Atom CPU with 8 GB RAM. Also using a fresh install of MySQL 8.0.12.
For some reason, even on idle condition, the mysqld.exe process consumes 300 MB of Memory. Also the CPU usage goes up to 60% during continuous query.

Both system runs on Windows 10 x64-bit

Obviously the speed of these two computers are different, but I kind of doubt that the CPU core is the issue, since the idle state already consume different memory.

What may went wrong with this MySQL inside the Atom based PC? Why does it behave very differently? CPU Usage aside, it is very weird to me that the idle state memory consumption is so different.
Is there any possible workaround to these issues?

Comment: Why are you saying something's wrong? 'not good enough' is really subjective and accounts for aspects not covered here, like what you regard as good enough.

Comment: The main issue is that MySQL behaves differently on the Atom core CPU. CPU Usage aside, the Memory it consumes even in the idle state is weirdly a lot more that when it is deployed in the i5 core CPU.

Comment: Maybe I should've just rephrase that last line to prevent misinterpretation of the main question

Comment: Being precise is an important part of IT. memory difference I assume is some configuration difference in the installation. Are they exactly the same 8.0 version. 20MB seems outrageously small.

Comment: Both are the exact same version of 8.0.12